# Detecting screen width for all Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css

When I simulate with Google Chrome inspector choosing the Galaxy S5 (360px), I am having problems detecting the proper screen width. It omits the CSS for the 360px and uses the 768px CSS instead. Is there a better way around this?

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 360px)  
{

    .header_2{width:100%;height:auto;padding:20px;}
    .left_obj{width:290px; position:relative;float:left;margin-bottom:20px;}
    .right_obj{width:290px; position:relative;float:left;}
    .mini_header{margin-bottom:20px;}

}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)  
{

    .header_2{width:100%;height:auto;padding:20px;}
    .left_obj{width:370px; position:relative;float:left;margin-bottom:20px;}
    .right_obj{width:370px; position:relative;float:left;}
    .mini_header{margin-bottom:20px;}

}
```

Comment: media condition for all mobile device with Landscape mode "@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) ", Use width: x%

Comment: The solution is just to set order of your css as #MukeshRam answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order or reverse of your media query. Write first 768 media query then 360.

Answer (score 1):

you can add meta to your header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

you can also refer to this link for full details
http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/